# How to display all registers while, filtering by id where id it should equal to another id inside an array (VUE 3)

Tags: json, vuejs3

so I have a headless for the static content and I am managing users with firebase and saving the favs articles in a Json file. My Json looks like this:

```
[
  {
  "id": “0000001”,
  "name": “Helga”,
  "favorites":
    [ “1234”, “6789” ]
  },
  {
    "id": “0000002”,
    "name": “Otto”,
    "favorites":
      [ “3334” ] 
    }
```

]
So I created a computed function to compare the current user id in firebase and the Json file, and then if is equal then I search in the user array "favorites" for the article id AND until here everything okay... however here it is my question, in the last line of the function below I want to display all the articles, where the id is equal to the ones inside the array(favorites), however because is an array this doesn't work. For testing purpose I placed the [0] at the end and I get the first one inside that user, so question is how to I get all of them? Should I use a different approach?

```
  displayFav(){
  if (firebase.auth().currentUser !== null) 
     var currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
     var filteredFav = this.favs.find(x => x.id === currentUser).favorites;

      return  this.response && this.response.allArticles.filter(a => a.id == filteredFav[0]);

}
```

Thank you for reading and your help. Let me know if you need to see something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare the value (`a.id`) against all values of the array (`filteredFav`), so instead of equals (`==`) you could use `includes()`

example:

```js
return  this.response && this.response.allArticles.filter(a => filteredFav.includes(a.id));
```

Comment: Hello Daniel thank you, I added a comment yesterday here and for some reason is not there. I have a small question, I was working this locally, however submitted my file to firebase with a change
{
  "userfav" : [ 
  {
   "id": “0000001”,
   "name": “Helga”,
   "favorites":
      [ “1234”, “6789” ]
  },
 ....
]
  }

Comment: So I created another function to connect to firebase, and apparently is working on the console, I'm getting the object. But back to the function when I arrive to the line of code : var filteredFav = dbValue.find(x => x.id === this.getCurrentUser).favorites; I get this in the console which is fine still: ["1234", "6789"] But then here---> this.response && this.response.allArticles.filter(a => filteredFav.includes(a.id)). Got an error "Cannot read property 'favorites' of undefined"

Comment: Hi, ignore my commet, I just needed an v-if=" displayFav" at the top because I was requesting the info before it was load : )